# Need to configure nginx to preserve url parameters after a redirect

Tags: nginx

So I need a little bit help with nginx configurations. The goal I'm trying to achieve is keeping the url parameters after a redirect.

For example when I access (the old url) [www.old.com/serivce/documentation7777/asdad2](http://www.old.com/serivce/documentation7777/asdad2) I want to be redirected to the new url preserving the url parameters [www.new.com/new-serivce/documentation7777/asdad2](http://www.new.com/new-serivce/documentation7777/asdad2)

Currently there is location block

```
location /servce/?(.*) { 
   return 301 https://www.new.com/new-service/$1$is_args$args; 
  }
```

When I try to access the old url just [www.old.com](http://www.old.com), I get redirected to https://www.new.com but when I add url parameters to the old url i get a 404.

Help needed please.

Comment: `location /servce/?(.*)` is wrong in two ways. Possible typo and missing regular expression operator. Should it be `location ~ ^/service/?(.*)$`?

Comment: Thanks the issue was with "~ ^" Now it's working